# Rails 5 ajax upload file with remotipart not work (send as HTML instead of JS )

Tags: ajax, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, remotipart

Rails 5 and carrierwave

I add:

```
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.3.1'
```

and

```
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

I have the form:

```
= simple_form_for state, remote: true do |f|
  = f.input :wsr
```

The output for that form:

```
<form class="simple_form" novalidate="novalidate" id="edit_odc_state_73" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/odc_states/73" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

But when i submit form:

```
Started PATCH "/odc_states/73" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-29 16:02:56 +0700
Processing by OdcStatesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "odc_state"=>{"wsr"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67ba393338 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161229-10725-1r3sn5z.txt>, @original_filename="test1.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"odc_state[wsr]\"; filename=\"test1.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n">}, "id"=>"73"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Why send as HTML, any ideas ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: In my case the error was from jquery handler - "onchange". Check your handlers.

Comment: I'm not using any jquery handler. Currently I'm building the functionality from scratch.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by replacing

```
//= require jquery-ujs
```

with

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

in `application.js` (Rails 5.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

add "authenticity_token: true"

```
simple_form_for state,
```

Comment: It didn't help, still send as HTML